# Show that $ABH_1H_2$ are concyclic

Tags: geometry, circles, 3d

Let $ABCD$ a tetrahedron and $H_1$, $H_2$ the intersections of the altitudes in the triangles $BCD$ and $ACD$. If $A, B, H_1, H_2$ are coplanar show that $ABH_1H_2$ are concyclic.

I noticed that the foot of the altitude from $A$ in $\triangle ACD$ is the same as the foot of the altitude from $B$ in $\triangle BCD$. Also, $AB\perp CD$. I draw $AO_1 \perp (BCD)$ and $BO_2 \perp (ACD)$. Then $A, O_2, H_2$ are on the same line and $B, O_1, H_1$ are on the same line. Now I have to show that $O_1O_2||H_1H_2$ and I have no idea to continue.

Comment: You seem to be overdoing it. A diagram should help a lot. Can you add one?

Comment: Recall that if a segment subtends same angle at two points lying on it's same side, then we get four concyclic points.

Comment: @MyMolecules I know that but how can I prove on this exercise?

Comment: If $BC\perp AD$ then is done

Comment: Did you draw a diagram? What is the measure of angle subtended by AB at $H_1$ and $H_2$?

Comment: Learn how to draw diagrams with Geogebra : even in 3D, it's easy. You will not go far in geometry if you do not draw figures for you and for others, as MyMolecules rightly asks for.